# Pull out Advanced Custom Fields in Related post plugin

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using Advanced Custom Fields plugin and microkid Related Posts.
I would like to display my custom fields inside Related post
This is what I got so far?

```
<?php //related artworks

$related = MRP_get_related_posts( $post->ID, true, false, 'quote_list' );

//for testing related array
//print_r ($related);

if(!empty($related)) {
    foreach($related as $key => $value) {
        $related = get_post($value);
        $related_id=$related->ID;
        $related_content=$related->post_excerpt;
        $related_url=$related->get_permalink;
        echo "<div><h4>".get_the_title($related_id)."</h4></div>";
        //echo get_the_post_thumbnail($related_id);
        echo "".$related_content."<br/><br/>";
        echo "<a href=".get_permalink($related_id).">read more</a>";
        //for testing related array
        //print_r ($related);
    }

}?>
```

But how I would pull out my advanced custom field?
Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to advenced custom fields you get the value with `get_field` http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/functions/get_field/

Just change "text_field" to your field-key.

```
<?php
$related = MRP_get_related_posts( $post->ID, true, false, 'quote_list' );

if( !empty( $related ) ) {
    foreach( $related as $key => $value ) { 

        // Get post
        $related = get_post( $value );

        // Get the field "text_field" on all posts
        $value = get_field( "text_field", $related->ID  );

        $output = '<div><h4>';
            $output .= get_the_title( $related->ID );
        $output .= '</div></h4>';

        // print the value from ACF

        if( $value ) {
            $output .= $value;
        }

        $output .= $related->post_excerpt;

        $output .= '<a href="'. get_permalink( $related->ID  ) .'">'. __('Read more','domain') .'</a>';
    }

    // Echo 
    echo $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function get_post_meta() to get data to a custom field. Include this function in your loop and set the right parameters. The first parameter is the id of the post ($related_id) , the second is the key, the meta tags key/name, and the third parameter set to true, if you get a single parameters.

To get all meta data use get_post_custom($related_id).

For identifier the data and key can you use the plugin Debug Objects, but currently only the git version.https://github.com/bueltge/Debug-Objects